# SwingWorker causing errors in subclasses

Tags: java, netbeans, swingworker

I have a Class(call it main class) and the method in main class calls methods of other classes.I have extended this main class in all other classes like this

```
      public class Evaluate extends Main
```

in my main class i am using swingworker ,so i have written the code like this

```
      class Main extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{
        public Main(GUI frame) {
        p = frame;

        }
        //some more code
```

Now when i build this program, it gives me the following error

```
        error: constructor Main in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
        public class Evaluate extends Main {
        required: GUI
        found: no arguments
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here GUI contains the main method from where my application starts.Kindly help me why this error is occurring.

Comment: don't create a `GUI/GUI's elements` inside `Backgroung tasks`, `SwingWorker` is about `get/put/modify` data `from/to` the `Objects` that exist before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend a class, you should call a constructor of the main class in your own constructor (by using `super`). So in this case, your `Evaluate` class should look like

```
public class Evaluate extends Main {

  public Evaluate( GUI frame ){
    super( frame );
  }
  // or another constructor
  public Evaluate( ){
    super( retrieveAFrameFromSomeWhere );
  }
  public Evaluate( loads of other arguments, GUI frame ){
    super( frame );
    //do something with the other arguments
  }
}
```

Check out the excellent [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for more information, and certainly the section about *Subclass constructors*